# Converting odd character encoding back to utf-8

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a database full of strings containing strange characters such as:

```
Design Tattoo Ãœbungshaut

MehrflÃ¤chiges Biozid Reinigungs- & Desinfektionsmittel
```

Where the `Ãœ` and `Ã¤` should be, as I understand, an `Ü` and `Ã` when in proper `UTF-8`.

Is there a standard function to revert these multiple characters back to there proper `UTF-8` form?

In `PHP` I have come across `$url = iconv('utf-8', 'iso-8859-1', $url);` which seems to get close but falls short. Perhaps I have the wrong parameters, but in any case was just wondering how well this issue is know and if there is an established fix?

The original data was taken from the eCommerce system `CubeCart` which seems to have no problem converting it back to normal text FYI.

Comment: what character set is the database? what character set are you outputting to?

Comment: database is utf8_unicode_ci and outputting to utf-8

Answer (score 0):

The data shown as example is UTF-8 encoded data mistakenly interpreted as ISO-8859-1 (or windows-1252). The problem combinations are in fact “Ü” and “ä” (“Ā” does not appear in German). So apparently what you need to do is to read the data as UTF-8 and display it that way, instead of converting it.

Comment: Thanks for this, the encoding for the page I am outputting it to is UTF-8. The reason for the conversion attempt as it was appearing in the incorrect form anyway. I have tried mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); above outputting the unaltered string to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If the database and output is utf-8 it could be because your not using utf-8 as the client character set.

If your using mysqli you can use [set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) or run `SET NAMES utf8` as a query before fetching data.

Comment: Thanks, this hasn't changed the output either.